# Pair to Mac over Internet Xamarin.iOS

Tags: macos, xamarin, ssh, xamarin.ios, noip

Is it possible with current version of VisualStudio and XCode 11.5 can we access the MacBuild machine over the internet?

I have configured Mac machine with remote login enabled, setup [noip](https://www.noip.com/), setup SSH port forwarding 22 on router and below are the results.

Initially, Pair to Mac has got the fingerprint but after providing the username and password it failed to authenticate as in picture 2.

any ideas ? or some one already using Pair to Mac over the internet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to ping or ssh into the mac from your computer?

Comment: Restart your mac and reopen your project, then try to connect again.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I can ping and ssh into mac, but no luck.

Comment: Please have a look at VS2019 logs: https://shrib.com/#TwoToedTreeSloth-rMLJ6o

Comment: Any ideas here ?